Is there a limit for list hyperlink columns?
I use a lot of SharePoint lists, often with 1 hyperlink-formatted column, but I've created a list with 6 hyperlink columns and any new items now take forever to save (well they don't save within 40 minutes of waiting!). Are multiple hyperlink columns beyond the limit of SharePoint?
It 'stumbled' with only 6 list items and maybe 20 hyperlinks added. I want to use SP, as opposed to Excel etc., as I want to have many filtered views of this list on various SharePoint pages on the site.
Thanks.

SharePoint Online does not have a specific limit on the number of hyperlink columns you can add to a list. However, there are some practical considerations and performance impacts to keep in mind:

Character Limit: Each hyperlink column has a 255-character limit. If your URLs are long, this can quickly add up and affect performance.
Performance: Having multiple hyperlink columns can slow down list operations, especially when adding or updating items. This is because each hyperlink column adds complexity to the list schema and increases the amount of data processed during save operations.

Workarounds:

Use Multiple Lines of Text: Instead of using multiple hyperlink columns, you can use a "Multiple lines of text" column with enhanced rich text enabled. This allows you to include multiple hyperlinks within the text and can help mitigate performance issues.
Link Shorteners: If the URLs are long, consider using link shorteners to reduce the character count before saving into the list items.

Useful references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits#Column%C2%A0
Max number of columns in a list in Sharepoint Online

